# Django aggregation for 3 related tables with one to one and one to many relation

Tags: django, postgresql

I have 3 django models (tables), let's say singer, album, and song.

**singer** has columns id, album_id (foreign key to album table), first_name, last_name

**album** has columns id, title, num_of_album_wishlist, num_of_album_stars

**song** has columns id, album (foreign key to album table) num_of_streams, song_duration_in_secs

Singer has one to one relation with album and album has one to many relation with song.

***these tables are just a dummy representation and don't necessarily makes sense but adequately demonstrate the problem.***

Have to create a queryset where for each **singer** (in the queryset), have to find out sum of *num_of_album_wishlist*, *num_of_album_stars* from *song* table, as well as total_num_of_songs for the user, sum of num_of_streams and song_duration_in_secs in a single queryset.

```
Singer.objects.annotate(
    wishlist=Sum('album__num_of_album_wishlist'),
    stars=Sum('album__num_of_album_stars'),
    streams=Sum('album__song_group__num_of_streams'),
    duration=Sum('album__song_group__song_duration_in_secs')
)
```

The query above gives wrong results pertaining to one to many relation of album table with song table.

```
subq = Singer.objects.annotate(
    streams=Sum('album__song_group__song_duration_in_secs'),
    duration=Sum('album__song_group__song_duration_in_secs')
    ).filter(pk=OuterRef('pk'))

queryset = Singer.objects.prefetch_related(
    'album').annotate(
    streams=Subquery(subq.values('streams')),
    duration=Subquery(subq.values('duration')),
    wishlist=Sum('album__num_of_album_wishlist'),
    stars=Sum('album__num_of_album_stars'),
    )
```

Using Subquery to tackle this works but generates different blocks for joining in SQL query (which further results in a long time to execute the query)

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to prefetch `album__song_group` in the subquery. It should become faster.